# How to create a subclass with more specific generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following code, I've outlined two problems (see comments):

1. I need a static method to return an instance of the current class. When it is called on a subclass (without being overwritten), it should return an instance of the subclass.
2. I need a generic to be more specific in a subclass (`Base` should take `BaseOptions` while `Sub` should take `SubOptions` which are a superset of `BaseOptions`).

Solutions with `extends BaseOptions | SubOptions` don't work for me, as I cannot enumerate all of the possible, more specific types of options to keep the code generic.

Am I approaching this the wrong way altogether or is there a solution to my problems?

```js
interface BaseOptions {
  a: string
}

interface SubOptions extends BaseOptions {
  a: string
  b: string
}

class Base<T extends BaseOptions> {
  options: T

  constructor(options: T) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  // Problem 1: When TypeScript is concerned, this method always returns an
  // instance of "Base", even when calling 'create' on a subclass (that does not
  // override 'create'). How can this be fixed?
  static create<T extends BaseOptions>(options: T): Base<T> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}

// Problem 2: Class 'Sub' requires more specific options than class 'Base', but
// TypeScript does not allow me to validate it:
//   2417: Class static side 'typeof Sub'
//         incorrectly extends base class static
//         side 'typeof Base'.
class Sub<T extends SubOptions> extends Base<T> {
  static create<T extends SubOptions>(options: T): Sub<T> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPIAczAD2IGyA3gLABQyycAXMhmFKAObUC+11oksiFAGUArgCM8BYqQgAPSCAAmpdFklES5arTGNmrEBxrIEeluy48qCADaYVAHgAqAPi3HC+DRkZPtJ6RYRBDBCKAAKTzBfAEp3WlowAAtgDAA6KO9kAF5kKP9uKkLqW3s0TAhnZDkFZXK1L2k3GoglR1d4pjA4AgQTKAgeyqdq+Va61RxGkhdI6Z9kJzjKY1oBsBEoEGQQCAB3ZGTUuakSGIBuAssqErsMUlExKpa25Ef1JtHa9rcV2mYesA+ggBkNnmNXu95rNMtJYp01hANlsdvtDikMCdvBcrkUrAhpIQbBA0jZCGxwpM0iDBpBwmQ6IwAOQAfTgTOQnBiMXxhOJpPJ4Ue1NBdIZDGQrPZABpkLpJSyxEzZaYFQgOVyYkA) work for you ?

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you @bogdanoff. But the problem is that a subclass **not** overriding `create` receives an instance of `Base` (at least TypeScript thinks so). How can I make it that it always returns an instance of the subclass, even when the subclass does not overwrite `create`?

Answer (score 1):

##### Short Answer:

Remove all the unnecessary stuff and keep it real. This works:

```
type BaseOptions = {
  a: string;
};

type SubOptions = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
} & BaseOptions;

class Base<BO extends BaseOptions> {
  options: BO;

  constructor(options: BO) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  static create<BO extends BaseOptions>(options: BO): Base<BO> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}

class Sub<SO extends SubOptions> extends Base<SO> {}
```

You can force TypeScript to use the correct type like this:

```
const sub = Sub.create({ a: 'a', b: 'b' }) as Sub<...>;
```

---

##### Long Answer:

This might be a TypeScript error - that's it; I really said that. Here is why I think so:

Using the code from the short answer we can create an object called `sub` like this:

```
const sub = Sub.create({ a: 'a', b: 'b' });
```

TypeScript will choose to type infer `Base<{ a: string, b: string }` - I am guessing you want to have the more explicit definition and infer the type `Sub<...>`.

To see what the underlying JS-Interpreter does, let's see what happens in node when using plain JavaScript.

```
class Base {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options
  }

  static create(options) {
    return new this(options)
  }
}

class Sub extends Base {}

Sub.create({ a: 'a', b: 'b' })
```

This outputs

```
> Sub { options: { a: 'a', b: 'b' } }
```

There you have it. That's the object with the correct class assigned; perfectly safe to overwrite the TypeScript inferred type.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IGenericMap<T> {
  [x: string]: T;
}
  
class Base<T extends IGenericMap<string>> {
  options: T

  constructor(options: T) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  static create<T extends IGenericMap<string>>(options: T): Base<T> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}

class Sub<T extends IGenericMap<string>> extends Base<T> {
  constructor(options: T) {
    super(options);
  }
}

console.log(Base.create({ a: 'one' }));
console.log(Sub.create({ a: 'one', b: 'two' }));
```

Now you can use the inheritance properly and the create methods returns the appropirate class.

If use the object mapping instead of **BaseOptions** and **SubOptions** inside the **IGenericMap** you are going to have any key with a generic value by choise. In the example above string and you can change it with any other type: **number**, **Object**, **any**, **string | number** ...

UPDATE: an example with types:

```
interface BaseOptions {
  a: string
}

interface SubOptions extends BaseOptions {
  a: string
  b: string
}
  
class Base<T extends BaseOptions> {
  options: T

  constructor(options: T) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  static create<T extends BaseOptions>(options: T): Base<T> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}

class Sub<T extends SubOptions> extends Base<T> {
  constructor(options: T) {
    super(options);
  }
}

console.log(Base.create({ a: 'one' }));
console.log(Sub.create({ a: 'one', b: 'two', c: '' }));
```

Comment: Thanks. What would the static `create` method in Sub look like though? I must override `create` in some cases. And what do you mean by `[x: string]` and how could this apply to my original example's `Options` interfaces?

Comment: { [x: string]: any } = { a: someValue, b: otherValue, cat: myCat, universe: what, anyKey: anyValue }

Comment: [x: string] is able to aggregate lots of key/value types. It is a generic solution where you can input lots of different key/value pairs as an input.

Comment: I thing that this example will work for you. And if not just use my old implmentation with the override method: class Sub<T extends IGenericMap<string>> extends Base<T> {
  static create<T extends IGenericMap<string>>(options: T): Sub<T> {
    return new this(options);
  }
}

Comment: Thanks. But what I do not see in either example is that the subclass is requiring a different type of `options`, **extending** the base options type.

Comment: Not required. You can input there any kind of value including BaseOptions and SubOptions

Comment: But I don't want the constructors and `create` methods to accept arbitrary options, but very specific ones, extending each other.

Comment: Now there is an update with using a types. I hope it will work for you.